# Show that $e^{|xy|}$ is not differentiable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm a little surprised and am not sure how to show that $e^{|xy|}$ is not differentiable. I am especially surprised because I know that $|xy|$ **is** differentiable at $(0, 0)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. **Edit:** I forgot to add that I am in particular interested in differentiability at $(0, 0)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact this function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. Its derivative at $(0,0)$ is zero. To see this we have to show that $\frac {e^{|xy|}-1} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} \to 0$ as $\|(x,y)\| \to 0$. For this note that that there exists $\delta >0$ such that $0<e^{t} -1\leq 2t$ for $0<t<\delta$. Hence $\frac {e^{|xy|}-1} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} \leq \frac {2|xy|} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}}$. Now use the inequality $\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}} \geq \sqrt {2|xy|}$ to see that $\frac {e^{|xy|}-1} {\sqrt {x^{2}+y^{2}}} \leq \sqrt 2 \sqrt {|xy|} \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: Wrong.  For $x=y$ we have $$\frac{e^{|x^2|}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}} = \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x} \to 0$$ same as for $x=0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you. I was wrong.  I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, $|xy|$ is not differentiable at any point where one of $x$ and $y$ is $0$, but not both.  $e^{|xy|}$ is non-differentiable at the same points.  Consider a direction where the nonzero variable is constant.

Comment: What about when $x = y = 0$?

Comment: It is differentiable there, with derivative $0$, since $2|xy| \le x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: Why is that enough to show that $|xy|$ is differentiable? But also apparently $e^{|xy|}$ is not differentiable at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the derivative of a function of several variables?  In particular, do you know that it is a linear transformation?

Comment: Are you talking about the total derivative or are you talking about taking partial derivatives as limits with associated difference quotients for each term? I am aware that the derivative is a linear transformation.

Comment: $e^f$ is differentiable wherever $f$ is differentiable.